# React Navigation passing custom data to the stacked screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to comprehend [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) to Navigate between screens in react-native.

So first I created a stacked view like this

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './home';
import CoinCapCharts from "./src/container/CoinCapCharts.js"

const screen = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  CoinCapCharts: { screen: CoinCapCharts}
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'none'
});

export default screen;
```

And then I added a `button` in my `Home` which would navigate to the `CoinCapCharts`

This how my button in `Home` looks like

```
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CoinCapCharts')}>
```

**[Question:]** Now I also want to send something as a props to my `CoinCapCharts` i.e if user clicks on `Bitcoin` container, I want to send something say `name` to `CoinCapCharts` so that it can display charts (& data) related to it. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use react-redux in conjunction with react-navigation. You will dispatch an action to update the state in the redux store before navigating to another component. Then the component receives props through the `mapStateToProps()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can send something(such as "name") you want as following.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('CoinCapCharts',
  { name: name,
    ... // otherthings to send
 });
```

And on CoinCapCharts screen, you can get the name value:
`this.props.navigation.state.params.name`